# Postman - how to check if one of three fields it not null

Tags: postman

I am getting an API response which provides a variety of fields.  Among them, there are three fields, where 2 of the 3 fields will be null and one will not be null.

How do I check, among the three fields, one is not null?

Answer (score 0):

### At least one not `null`

You can use the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) if you want **at least one** to be not `null`.

```js
pm.test("One not null", () => {
    const parsedResponseBody = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(Object.values(parsedResponseBody).some(v => v !== null)).to.be.true;
})
```

Test will success for a response body like this:

```json
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": null,
    "prop3": "notNull"
}
```

and for a response body like this:

```json
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": "notNull",
    "prop3": "notNull"
}
```

### Exactly one not `null`

##### If you don't know what the other values will be

For exactly one you can just count the occurrences of a specific value (`null` in this case) using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

This is most-likely what you want and it's very simple to customize e.g. if you suddenly want exactly 2, 3, 4, etc. values to be non-null.

```js
pm.test("Expected count not null", () => {
    const parsedResponseBody = pm.response.json();
    const expectedCount = 1;
    pm.expect(
        Object.values(parsedResponseBody)
        .reduce((total, value) => value !== null ? total + 1: total, 0)
    ).to.equal(expectedCount);
})
```

Test will success for a response body like this:

```json
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": null,
    "prop3": "notNull"
}
```

but fail for a response body like this
and for a response body like this:

```json
{
    "prop1": null,
    "prop2": "notNull",
    "prop3": "notNull"
}
```

##### If you know what the other property values will be

If you know which values the other properties will have you can also use the following approach using [`all.members()`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/)

```js
pm.test("Expected count not null", () => {
    const parsedResponseBody = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(Object.values(parsedResponseBody)).to.have.all.members([null, null, "notNull"])
})
```